# Best Pattern for ASP.NET MVC 5 With EF 6.2?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am working on big scale enterprise application using .net stack, at the moment I am using layered approach. The main problem I am facing at my data layer because I am using static connection context and have following issues.

1. Can't use parallel calls because of static behavior.
2. Can't use sync methods.
3. Caching may have another issue

So now we have decided to change our Data layer there are couple of things in our consideration like repository and unit of work but we are not sure what kind of problems we face in it as we have enterprise scale application having 600 plus tables.

In order to write such big story I would like to take help from community which approach I should follow.

Please provide me any suitable links or thoughts.

Comment: Feel free to join the ineradicable repository/UoW discussion. Only, not here please. These questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER use a static EF context in a multi-user application such as a web app.  EF maintains state, and when multiple users are accessing the data it can conflict and corrupt the data context.  Consider saving a user, if two people are saved at the same time, only one will win out.

Answer (score 0):

This is madness to use static database connection firstly :) Your designer's idea was very bad about on static aproach. I think NTiear architecture was a good way to start on this. May in the future your another problem will be scalibty of your db system. Probably you use  vertical scaling aproach. If it is correct you have to manage apply distribited aproach on db system like replication and sharding.  Also nosql solution may hava another option.
I searched this topic the previous year and I wrote a document, you can see on [medium](https://medium.com/@eyupcanarslan/war-of-managements-system-nosql-against-rdbms-c24b69b3de4e)

And another issue on monolotihc vs. microservice. You can find many article on medium or etc. Here is one of [them](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/monolith-vs-microservices-which-architecture-is-right-for-your-team-bb840319d531).

As additionally , I published a sample project on github about on 
[N-Tier-Architecture-with-Generic-Repository--Dependency-Injection-And-Ninject](https://github.com/EyupCanARSLAN/N-Tier-Architecture-with-Generic-Repository--Dependency-Injection-And-Ninject)

you can may examine

Good luck ;)